# gRPC-nodejs : Disabling AF_INET6 sockets because ::1 is not available

Tags: node.js, grpc

I used grpc in my nodejs application, but I got a problem 'Disabling AF_INET6 sockets because ::1 is not available.', my grpc version 
is 0.14.1, node version is v4.2.4. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message indicates that gRPC was unable to use IPv6 sockets, so it fell back to using only IPv4 sockets. It is purely informational, and does not indicate that there was an error or that your RPC failed. That message has been silenced in the most recent release of the gRPC package.

Comment: thank you very much, this question has beset me long time.your answer's mean gRPC using only IPv4? but my production environment is IPv6 ? so it warning this message? forgive me for my  speak english not very well, thanks for your answer.

Comment: All the error message says is that it tried to use IPv6 and failed, so it's using IPv4 instead. It doesn't say why it failed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again.