# Request to Kubernetes Pod from PHP GRPC client (from Docker)

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes, grpc, portforwarding

everyone!
The situation is like this:
I have a pod in kubernetes, I forward a port to it like this -
`kubectl port-forward deploy/reporter-dev 8585:8081 --address 0.0.0.0.0`

I connect from Postman to my local address 192.168.31.205:8585 - the server from kubernetes responds correctly.

But as soon as I try to connect from PHP application from Docker nothing works.

[image: POSTMAN is working fine]

This is connection code from PHP: (php classes generated from PROTO before)

```
class GroupService
{
    private ReportGroupsClient|BaseStub|null $reportGroupsClient;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reportGroupsClient = Yii::$container->get(
            ReportGroupsClient::class,
            ['192.168.31.205:8585', [
                'credentials' => ChannelCredentials::createInsecure(),
            ]]
        );
    }

    public function getReportGroupsList()
    {
        $res = $this->reportGroupsClient->GetList(new ReportGroupsGetListRequest([
            'limit' => 10,
            'offset' => 0,
        ]))->wait();

        //exec('/var/www/grpcurl -insecure 192.168.31.205:8585 retail.reporter.ReportGroups/GetList', $res);

        return $res;
    }
}
```

```
public function actionHealth(): void
{
    $this->log("Start DEBUG gRPC");

    $rr = new GroupService();
    $res = $rr->getReportGroupsList();
    var_dump($res);
    $this->log("End of debug");
}
```

that return the error:

```
/var/www # GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug GPRC_TRACE=all php yii reports/report/health
I0210 07:22:57.540640544     357 ev_epoll1_linux.cc:121]     grpc epoll fd: 4
D0210 07:22:57.540835960     357 ev_posix.cc:171]            Using polling engine: epoll1
D0210 07:22:57.541246752     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "grpclb"
D0210 07:22:57.541344669     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "rls_experimental"
D0210 07:22:57.541406252     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "priority_experimental"
D0210 07:22:57.541479794     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "weighted_target_experimental"
D0210 07:22:57.541527044     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "pick_first"
D0210 07:22:57.541548752     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "round_robin"
D0210 07:22:57.541621877     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "ring_hash_experimental"
D0210 07:22:57.541887044     357 certificate_provider_registry.cc:33] registering certificate provider factory for "file_watcher"
D0210 07:22:57.541919794     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "cds_experimental"
D0210 07:22:57.541977919     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "xds_cluster_impl_experimental"
D0210 07:22:57.542039169     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "xds_cluster_resolver_experimental"
D0210 07:22:57.542087877     357 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "xds_cluster_manager_experimental"
2023-02-10 07:22:57 Start DEBUG gRPC
D0210 07:22:57.649119960     357 dns_resolver.cc:162]        Using native dns resolver
I0210 07:22:57.652611710     359 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:429] Disabling AF_INET6 sockets because ::1 is not available.
I0210 07:22:58.759204128     357 subchannel.cc:948]          subchannel 0xffff81952db0 {address=ipv4:192.168.31.205:8585, args=grpc.client_channel_factory=0xffff8195d050, grpc.default_authority=192.168.31.205:8585, grpc.internal.channel_credentials=0xffff81916b90, grpc.internal.security_connector=0xffff8191be30, grpc.internal.subchannel_pool=0xffff8191a740, grpc.resource_quota=0xffff8191c420, grpc.server_uri=dns:///192.168.31.205:8585}: connect failed: {"created":"@1676013778.758779961","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2572,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1676013778.758739461","description":"Socket closed","fd":6,"file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":802,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:192.168.31.205:8585"}]}
I0210 07:22:58.759450044     357 subchannel.cc:888]          subchannel 0xffff81952db0 {address=ipv4:192.168.31.205:8585, args=grpc.client_channel_factory=0xffff8195d050, grpc.default_authority=192.168.31.205:8585, grpc.internal.channel_credentials=0xffff81916b90, grpc.internal.security_connector=0xffff8191be30, grpc.internal.subchannel_pool=0xffff8191a740, grpc.resource_quota=0xffff8191c420, grpc.server_uri=dns:///192.168.31.205:8585}: Retry immediately
I0210 07:22:58.759495461     357 subchannel.cc:914]          subchannel 0xffff81952db0 {address=ipv4:192.168.31.205:8585, args=grpc.client_channel_factory=0xffff8195d050, grpc.default_authority=192.168.31.205:8585, grpc.internal.channel_credentials=0xffff81916b90, grpc.internal.security_connector=0xffff8191be30, grpc.internal.subchannel_pool=0xffff8191a740, grpc.resource_quota=0xffff8191c420, grpc.server_uri=dns:///192.168.31.205:8585}: failed to connect to channel, retrying
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#241 (3) {
    ["metadata"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["code"]=>
    int(14)
    ["details"]=>
    string(34) "failed to connect to all addresses"
  }
}
2023-02-10 07:22:58 End of debug
```

If I uncomment "exec" function - **grpcurl answer correctly!**

From this I conclude that the request from the Docker container works fine, but the GRPC client specifically does not work for some reason. What can it be?

Comment: Hello @Makinaru, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Disabling AF_INET6 sockets because ::1 is not available` says that it tried to use IPv6 and failed, so it's using IPv4 instead. That message has been silenced in the most recent release of the gRPC package. Check your gRPC version, if required update to the recent version. Refer to the similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689921/grpc-nodejs-disabling-af-inet6-sockets-because-1-is-not-available) for more information.

**DNS resolution failure with gRPC:** Looks like you're using a workaround to run your binary under environment variable setting: `GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER=native`, still you're getting the below error:

```
`connect failed: {"created":"@1676013778.758779961","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2572,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1676013778.758739461","description":"Socket closed","fd":6,"file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":802,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:192.168.31.205:8585"}]`}
```

See github issue on [Endpoint read failed in client request #144](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/144) which may help to resolve your issue.